# Building a Unity project into iOS without Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I want to build my Unity project to the iOS platform.

When I click build to iOS I get prompted with this screen:

[image: Screen to build a project]

There says `Run in Xcode as` but I do not have a Mac, but correct me if I am wrong but you can not run Xcode on Windows.

So is there no way I can build my project without a Mac then?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can’t, when you build for iOS, unity creates a project that you must open with XCode (in a Mac) and then build it to deploy it on a device or simulator.

Comment: Can you get XCode on Windows?

Comment: No, XCode is available only for MacOS. Alternatively there are paid cloud services to “rent” a MacOS system.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "vmware", there are good tutorials on youtube, but not sure it's legal.